# How to set Balance Ragged Lines as a paragraph style?

Tags: adobe-indesign

I was experimenting with Balance Ragged Lines after discovering that [Adobe are trying to make it work on web text](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/45117/3327) (seeing if it can handle dynamic text from data merge - turns out it can).

I couldn't find it in the Paragraph Styles options, and [Adobe's help docs](http://helpx.adobe.com/indesign/using/aligning-text.html) and everything else on it I could find just tell you to set it one paragraph at a time from the Paragraph window flyout menu, no mention of paragraph styles.

Is there a way I'm just not seeing?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I was looking in the wrong sections - it is there, under "**Indents and spacing**".

Didn't think to look there the first couple of times, since it's not an indent or spacing - but thinking about it, it makes sense for it to be in the same place as Align to Grid and Alignment.

[image]

Comment: You're correct. You should come back and and accept your answer so that the question shows as answered on the site.